# How to pass a list collection from Razor View to Javascript?

Tags: list, razor, datatable

How to pass list collection from Razor view code to Javascript for loading data into a datatable?

Let's say, there is a list of employees from a view model, then how to expose that list to Javascript code in order to use that list collection as datasource for HTML datatable.

Example:

Razor View Code:

@model EmployeeVM

@{
var employeeList = Model.EmployeeList

}

JavaScript:

var employeeArray = JSON.parse(employeeList)